# Forcing CSS style attribute to center elements on a page

Tags: html, css

I have a scenario where I have a complex web app that uses a lot of CSS/JS frameworks/libs and a `<div>` on one of my pages isn't rendering correctly.

Here's my code snippet, but I unfortunately can't provide a full code example because of the numerous JS/CSS frameworks involved:

```
<body>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;" id="centerme">
        <h1 style="margin: 0 auto;">You'll need an invitation to access<br/>retailer connection setups</h1>

        <div style="margin: 0 auto;" class="well">
            <h2>How can I get such wow?</h2>
            <h3>
                It looks like you need much amaze.
            </h3>
        </div>

        <h3>For reals? Rejoice!</h3>
    </div>
</body>
```

So what I'm trying to do is center everything inside the `centerme` div horizontally. Currently the above attempt isn't working, but according to [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/), I just need to apply the following style to my div:

```
.centerme {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Now it is my *understanding* that any `style` attribute I apply to any HTML element will always take precedence over other styles/rules governing that element, yes?!? So why then is it *not* taking precedence in my code?

In other words: **What `style` attributes can I set that will force the browser to center my div no matter what other rules have been defined?**

Comment: Is it taking precedence in your code? check your page with the browsers inspector and see if the `margin:auto;` is being overridden by another style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your div needs to have a defined width for the margin auto to work:

**Set Width:**

```
#centerme {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to center a dynamic width would just be to display it inline-block, then center it with `text-align:center;`. (I am assuming you mean the width isn't set and depends on the content) The `absolute` method only works if a width is set as well.

Comment: @Jacob Gray, true, my bad. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center dynamic width element, you could either:

```css
.centerme {
  display: table; /*shrink-to-fit*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerme">yes</div>
```

or:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
.container .centerme {
  text-align: left; /*reset if necessary*/
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="centerme">yes</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is an ID `<div style="margin: 0 auto;" id="centerme">`

but you pointed as a class `.centerme {}`

You must use `#` to point an ID `#centerme {}`

Also `#centerme` must have a defined `width`

**example:**

```
#centerme {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```